# ECS public subnet service communication with private subnet service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, service-discovery

If I have a ECS Fargate Service ( web-tier ) deployed in a public subnet & a ECS Fargate Service ( app-tier ) deployed in a private subnet within the same VPC, what would be a best practice for communication between the two ?

Is ECS Service discovery the right way to go about it. If so, how do I go about using it in this scenario ?

Comment: Communicate how? You can use internal load balancer, service discovery or some indirect way of doing this (e.g. queues).

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this?

Comment: yes, I used Service discovery endpoints to communicate between them. There is no need to go through the internet with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your architecture needs to be looked at.

The only thing in your public subnet should be public load balancer. ECS for both tiers should be in private subnet. This setup means that both web and app services could live on this same ECS Fargate cluster.

This should simplify your setup.